# Cython: What is the fastest way to read values from a typed memoryview array?

Tags: c, optimization, cython

I have made a number of routines in cython over the years, and been relatively satisfied with the performance, until a colleague on Friday pointed out that I was only getting a 17x speedup. I had thought the speedups where much greater. So I used the `cython -a program.pyx` app to take a look at the generated code. [Here is a link to the report](http://folk.uio.no/mariujon/cy.html). I tend to make loops where I make non-linear mathematical operations, like in this while loop:

```
cdef double simps(double[:] integrand, double[:] r):
        cdef int n = len(integrand)
        cdef int m = (n-1)/2
        cdef double s = 0.0
        cdef int i = 0
        while (i<m):
            s += (r[2*(i+1)] - r[2*i])*(integrand[2*i] + 4.0*integrand[2*i + 1] + integrand[2*i+2])
            i += 1
        return s/6.
```

The following line seems to take a long time to evaluate.

```
s += (r[2*(i+1)] - r[2*i])*(integrand[2*i] + 4.0*integrand[2*i + 1] + integrand[2*i+2])
```

The reason is that the generated code makes an awful lot of checks of this type:

```
__pyx_t_4 = (2 * (__pyx_v_i + 1));
__pyx_t_5 = -1;
if (__pyx_t_4 < 0) {
  __pyx_t_4 += __pyx_v_r.shape[0];
  if (unlikely(__pyx_t_4 < 0)) __pyx_t_5 = 0;
} else if (unlikely(__pyx_t_4 >= __pyx_v_r.shape[0])) __pyx_t_5 = 0;
if (unlikely(__pyx_t_5 != -1)) {
  __Pyx_RaiseBufferIndexError(__pyx_t_5);
  {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 8; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
}
```

To me it looks like it might be checking that the read values actually `r[2*i], r[2*i+1]` etc are not beyond the limit of the array itself.

Can you propose a solution that doesn't induce these checks and possibly explain why it works better?

Comment: You might want to take a look at adding some of the compiler directives listed [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives) such as boundscheck and wraparound. You can annotate your cython function with these special decorators to eliminate these checks you are seeing.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon if you would like to copy-paste your comment into a reply; I will then accept it as the answer. It solved the problem

Comment: Ok will do, am glad that it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at adding some of the compiler directives listed [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives) such as boundscheck and wraparound. You can annotate your cython function with these special decorators to eliminate these checks you are seeing.

Comment: Can I add - do try to understand what the directives actually do and when they apply (e.g. `boundscheck` applies to memoryviews and typed `ndarray`s but not to pointers or to ordinary Python lookups). A lot of people add them to everything in a "cargo cult" type way. I sometimes prefer to use `with cython.boundcheck(False)` to scope the directive only to the bit of code where it's needed.